# What is the origin and history of the word "motherf---er"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, slang, history, offensive-language

I'm not a native English speaker, but I would like to know how and why people started using *mother fucker*.  Today it seems it has lost its meaning because people use it all the time, but was there a time in history when *mother fucker* meant something different?

I know we see it in the movies sometimes, but did people call each other *mother fuckers* 100 years ago?  How about 500 years ago? what about 1000 years ago?

And why don't we have *father fuckers*?  Is mother fucker only used on guys?

Comment: @user1344784I don't like your attitude. Such obscenities shouldn't be projected around such a reputable site. Besides, it might ruin some eight year old who is a new member.

Comment: @Third Idiot: Discussion about language get pretty annoying when words are bowdlerized. The [policy](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/561), as far as I understand it, is to [mildly censor question titles](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/975), and add adequate tagging (here, *slang* and *vulgar*). No more. If you object, please raise this on [meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Third Idiot: this is a valid question for this site. It is recommended to mildly censor the title, but not the body. (See [meta question one](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/446/), [meta question two](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/253/).) Also, eight-year old new members are not allowed round here anyway, as per the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

Comment: this is discussed by the narrator (Vonnegut in effect) in Slaughterhouse 5: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/9611921-get-out-of-the-road-you-dumb-motherfucker-the-last

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most fortuitously  for you, just a couple of days ago I stumbled upon a book that answers this and most any question one might have on the word *fuck* and its multitudinous derivatives — anyone who has the slightest bit curiosity about this subject would do well to check out Jesse Sheidlower's [The F-word](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195393112), a very accessible and fun book. In writing the book, the author had access to the Oxford English's Dictionary's archives — the most extensive and renowned of all dictionaries — so what he has to say is likely the final word on the matter.

Let's start at the beginning of your questions.   First of all, the germ of the idea behind the word *motherfucker* is likely very old. I'd imagine that since the dawn of language more than 200,000 years ago, people have been insulting one another by attacking their mothers.  To appreciate the thrust of the insult *motherfucker* doesn't require knowledge of the technology, or culture, or local history of any particular milieu; the logic behind it is virtually ageless, because it is undergirded by a fundamental evolutionary truth, instinctually apparent to every creature since sex first came about — and that truth is that a mother's fidelity is dear, to both her and her partner, and it is mostly unfavorable circumstances that serve to erode it.

That was a mouthful.  Let's make it clearer.   Insulting a mother's fidelity is so powerful because it lies at the nexus at many of the most fundamental issues that a successful marriage must negotiate — saying *I fucked your mother* is a many pronged insult that implies a large score of unpleasant things.   Indeed, it suggests that:

- Your father is foolish and dull.  He has no idea, or no power, to keep his wife from another man.  Your mother two-times him with impunity.
- Your mother is a slut and a harlot.  Not only does she cuckold your father, but she does so wantonly in marriage, and one implication is that she might too be busy getting some to adequately take care of you and your siblings.
- You are illegitimate, and can receive no legitimate property, because your mother is not good enough to make it into your father's stable of wives; she's no better than a common whore. Because of her sluttiness, your warden of a father cannot be sure that you are his, and thus he will not chance any of his life's hard work on possibly another man's child, an evolutionary disaster if there ever was one.
- Your father is pathetic, and unable to provide for you.  His prospects are dim, and things are so bad in your household that your mother must turn her attentions to another man so that you and your siblings get enough to eat.   Not only is she in his debt, but figuratively, so are you and your father.

Further reasoning along the same lines shows why an insult like *father fucker* or some such that would be nonsensical; a father's fidelity simply isn't as important to the health of a household as a mother's is.  Unlike a mother, a father can simply work to support all of the fruits of his dalliances; in fact, as long as you are a legitimate son, *a father fucker* might be an epithet you look upon with equanimity.  It suggests that your father is powerful, or rich enough to be able to enjoy such a position. The asymmetry arises from an iron law:  A member of the male sex in desperate straits is likely to be less promiscuous, not more, because no female in need of property will accept him; a woman in desperate straits is likely to be more promiscuous, not less, because access to her sex is the only thing she has to sell.

Thus, it isn't hard to see why a *motherfucker*, someone who *fucks mothers*, would easily become a byword of opprobrium and contempt; to have a potential *motherfucker* walking about is to have an existential insult that threatens a man's very identity as a legitimate member of his household.

---

With that behind us, let's go to the etymology.   Unfortunately, some of the etymologies that are given here are nonsensical, since as *The F-Word* clearly notes, the word *fuck* itself was not attested until the end of the 15<sup>th</sup> century.  It clearly came into its own as a vulgar word in the 16<sup>th</sup> and 17<sup>th</sup> centuries, replacing the word *swife*. However, given the puritanical nature of publication in those days, was not recorded in a English dictionary till 1775, and only till 1891 were more than a couple of words and a few quotations jotted down about it, in John Farmer's and W.e. Henley's *Dictionary of Slang and Its Analogues.*

You see, that was the nature of vulgarities back then; they might prosper in spoken English but would be scarcely written down until the late 19<sup>th</sup> centuries.  [The book tells an amusing anecdote of a defendant rebutting a slander judgment against him by claiming as late as 1846 that *fuck*, the word he slandered a woman with, was not an English word.]  Thus, we cannot be sure that *motherfucker*, borne of *fuck* was not actually attested in speech by the dates we have first written attestation, and sadly enough they are the only products amenable to historical investigation.

In any case, here are the first few citations given for the earliest known definition, *a despicable or contemptible person*:

> **1918** *Letter in Journal of American History* LXXXI 1585: Your low-down Mother Fuckers can put a gun in our hands but who is able to take it out? [**1918** in H. De Witt *Bawdy Barrack-Room Ballads*: The little red run he grew and grew/fucked his mother and sister too.]  **1928** C. McKay *Banjo* 229:  I've been made a fool of by many a skirt, but its the first time a mother-plugger done got me like this.

The word *motherfucker* then really took off in the Army in World Wars, giving the second sense, *a fellow; a person; an admire person; a formidable person*:

> **1958** *Stack a Lee* (typescript, Kinsey Institute) 1: He...said who put the hole in this motherfucker's head/Who could the murderer of this poor man **1964** R.D Abrahams *Deep down in Jungle* (Appendix II) 261: One of the best things which can be said of a man is that he is a "mean motherfucker" or a "tough motherfucker", but to call him just a "mother-fucker" is to invite reprisal.

And after the Wars, and the return of the troops, I'm supposing it exploded onto the popular consciousness as result of vanishing indecency standards in the '60s, and that was that.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was previously under the impression it originated in WW2 to mean someone who had sex with French or German housewives.

Comment: Hmm. I've always understood "motherfucker" as implying incest. As in, the person so described has sex not just with any wife, but *his own mother*. Is this interpretation incorrect?

Comment: @Marthaª - Me too. But I was told by an American friend not to take these motherfucking cuss words literally!

Comment: Wait, wouldn't father fucker means someone who fuck with fathers? How come you said, "a father fucker might be an epithet you look upon with equanimity. It suggests that your father is powerful, or rich enough to be able to enjoy such a position." Would not that, father fucker, be the same with saying, "you're gay," and even worse since it can also means, "you're an incest gay," if the father were to refer to the target's father.

Comment: "Mostly" = The Best :)

Comment: @絢瀬絵里 Until recently, male gay sex wasn't taboo under all circumstances. For example, the Vikings used `receiver of gay sex` as one of their worst possible insults, however, `giver of gay sex` was in no way insulting. That is, it isn't the homosexuality itself that was derided, it was a man making himself subservient. A male choosing to be "effeminate" was shameful in their culture. Also, in ancient Greece older men would often take on pubescent boys as lovers. Since the boy was already in a socially submissive role, this wasn't considered inappropriate.

Comment: this is unbarable drivel, sorry. I would usually share in the exitement, but it is not supported by the little actual content. Also I feel slightly insulted by your using 2nd person pronouns. Who, me? F\*\*k you, right. Besides, the insight that the attestation of obscene slang may be inherently unreliable should go without saying. It's good you mention it though explicitly not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Etymology lists *–er* as attested from 1956, with *–ing* from 1933, however interestingly it lists the clipped form, simply *mother* (with context implied), since 1928, which to me means that the phrase was established earlier, but not attested.

I have to question Thrid Idiot's 14th century, as most writings about Oedipus come from [5th century BC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus#5th_century_BC).

EDIT:
According to [Jim Dawson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Dawson)'s "The Compleat Motherfucker: A History of the Mother of All Dirty Words", page [14](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932595414)

> Possibly the earliest literary use of the term motherfucker was in the Ionic poetry of [Hipponax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipponax), who accused a sculptor who had insulted him of being a *metrokoites*.

(which was also around 5 BC)

Dawson mentions Marquis de Sade (1740 – 1814) arrested for using the phrase and the first written occurrence in a Texas Court of Appeals in 1890.

<sub>Disclaimer: Hipponax story seems plausible and founded (see [here](http://www.michaelschmidt.org.uk/pp008.shtml)), for Marquis de Sade I have to wonder what would be the French phrase as there is no similar phrase even today.</sub>

Comment: "I have to wonder what would be the French phrase as there is no similar phrase even today." There's the imperative ... *ta mere*. *koites*, while similar in form and meaning, does surprisingly have no direct relation to *coitus* (*co-* + *ite* "go") but is explained as κοίτη (koítē, “bed”; also "act of going to bed; bedtime", though \'key- "to lie down" could of course relate to \'kom- "with" and \**h₁éyti "go", too) and *-ites* + NOM seems to mark an attributive genetive, jsyk. Best answer on this page by far.

Answer (score 4):

In his 1970 book *Seize the Time*, former Black Panther Bobby Seale attributes the term to slaves in the American South:

> Eldridge [Cleaver] ran it down to me once…he said, “I’ve seen and heard brothers use the word four and five times in one sentence and each time the word had a different meaning and expression.
>
> “Motherfucker actually comes from the old slave system and was a reference to the slave master who raped our mothers, which society today doesn’t want to face as a fact. But today, check the following sentences: ‘Man, let me tell you. This motherfucker here went down there with his motherfucking gun, knocked down the motherfucking door and blew this motherfucker’s brain’s out. This shit is getting to be a motherfucker.’”

Comment: Nice work! I'm going to have to read that.

Comment: Sadly Seale was wrong. A variant of it appears in Shakespeare.

Comment: @Mary - Intriguing. Could you cite a reference to this Shakespearian usage please?

Answer (score 2):

In most cultures coitus with one's mother (and by extension incest in general) has been taboo pretty much since records/civilisation began. The reasons for this are almost certainly related to the genetic consequences (read 'aberration') that can arise from such activities.

Therefore most cultures/languages have concepts very closely related to 'motherf4cker' - certainly the story of Oedipus is probably the most well-known example of the concept in popular and ancient culture, and correspondingly words to describe the practice(s) involved.

My own (limited knowledge) of languages other than English allows me to offer '[mata chodh](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=madarchod)' and 'bahin chodh' (other chodhs are available)  which is from Hindi and other Indo-Aryan languages (meaning: 'mother-' and 'sister-f4cker' respectively).

Presumably the concept is a strong taboo in African cultures which may explain the popularity of the Anglicised version in modern US African-American discourse.

Answer (score 0):

I heard "motherfucker" was related to a "colloquial" English term (Cheaper by the dozen) that actually refers to plantation owners forcing young black male slaves when they became old enough to climax, to put sackcloth over their heads and impregnate their mothers, resulting in a "dozen" "cheap" children. (Children with severe birth defects).

Comment: For a discussion of "cheaper by the dozen," see ["Cheaper by the dozen" phrase origin?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/486088/cheaper-by-the-dozen-phrase-origin)

Comment: To the downvoters: note that this was posted first as a question and closed as duplicate with reference to this question. So don't comment here voting it down for lack of reference. Go there vote reopen the question for a source to this claim. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/559135/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-motherfer As far as I care it should sit idly at 0 points in the mean while.

Answer (score -2):

I was told it originated in Africa where many of the tribal religions worship mother nature. So in essence it refers to someone disrespecting mother nature. In this sense it is not related to incest. Cannot verify any of this but the word does seem to be primarily African-American.